# Excel File Exact Match?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to show unique value (value that appear in column B, and not appear at columnA) in UniqueList column

I want to have unique value where the word length is same.

Wondering how to modify to do exact match filtering?

bb shouldn't appear since value at column A is "bb e" and I only want

[image]

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot this. What's in B9? Where does your table start? Is "bb" and "e" in the same cell? The data sample above does not help. Please post a screenshot so the real data layout can be seen.

Comment: Hi teylyn, sorry.. I just updated a screenshot of real layout with formula inside.

Answer (score 0):

The formula works correctly. The Match returns an error. The formula returns B4 if Match is an error. I guess what you really want is the other way round, i.e. if it is an error, return an empty string, otherwise return the value. That would be (starting in C2 and copied down)

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$A$1:$A$10,0)),"",B2)
```

The result is this: blank for row 4, since "bb" is no match. Matches only for row 3 and 7, since "aa" and "oo" are present in column A.

[image]

Comment: I see, but what I want to show in C column is non matching unique value that appear in B column only.  It should be showing C2=1, C4= (nothing since not exact match), C5=gg

Comment: Please update your question and describe what you want to achieve in more detail. If you want non-matching unique values, then "bb" as a result of your formula in row 4 is correct, no? Because it is *not* a match in column A (there is no "bb" in column A, just a "bb e") and it is unique in column B, just like the 1 in row 2.